# perl one liners + match word and delete string after separator

Tags: linux, solaris, ksh, perl

I work with linux/solaris machines
and I need to add some rule in my ksh script:

Please advise how to match the password word in file,  and delete the value password after the separator "=" with perl liner command

second it will delete only the first password!

For example

```
  more file  ( before delete the password )

  Password fkwf324ei23
  Password=fkwf324ei23
  Pass_word=fevme
  Secret_Password=vrev873662j
  Password=fkwf324ei23
```

.

```
   more file ( after delete the password )

   Password fkwf324ei23
   Password=
   Pass_word=fevme
   Secret_Password=vrev873662j
   Password=fkwf324ei23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace Password= at a beginning of a line followed by anything with the string `Password=`:

```
perl -i~ -pe 's/^Password=.*/Password=/' file
```

### Update

To only replace the first occurence, add a flag:

```
perl -i~ -pe '$changed = s/^\s*Password=.*/Password=/ unless $changed;' file
```

Comment: Just one remark Password can be some spaces from the begining ( so maybe need to remove the "^" ?

Comment: @Eytan: Removing the `^` would match `Secret_Password`. That's not what you want. Just add "optional spaces": `^ *Password`, or even `^\s*Password` if there can be tabs and other whitespace, too.

Comment: +1. You can reduce that a bit: `s/^\s*Password=\K.*//`

Comment: ok , please advice - what need to add in your syntax so it will delete only the first password , once he find the first it will delete it but no the others ( because file can contain other Password , and I want to delete only the first one in my file )

Comment: see my update in the question

Comment: @Eytan: See my update in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to change the first occurence and keep the rest of the file you need some state here:

```
perl -i~ -pe 'BEGIN { $y=1 }; ($y) && (s/^Password=\K.*//) && ($y=0)' file
```